# Laravel "The page has expired due to inactivity" after switching fastcgi_pass from network socket to unix socket

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

I'm running a website on nginx and was using a network socket so far to process php, with the following conf line

```
fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
```

The problem is this socket points to php7.0 and I wanted to upgrade to php7.2 (which is installed on the server). I changed the line to the following

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

The php is indeed executed, but whenever I try to log into my website, I get an error message from laravel "The page has expired due to inactivity". Nothing is logged so I don't have any idea what's going on...

Any idea why switching to a unix socket would break that?

Comment: This seems related to the CSRF token, you can check if everything is ok with your session and perhaps try a different session driver in the Laravel config.

Comment: I agree it seems linked to CSRF token, but what breaks it is only switching between a unix socket and a network socket for PHP processing so not sure why a session driver would work with one but not the other?